# Algebraic Combinations of Convergent Sequences in Metric Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I'm learning analysis and in going from real sequences to sequences in a general metric space, I noticed that the theorem for the limits of algebraic combinations of convergent sequences was conspicuously absent. In other words, when I try to extend the theorem for sequences (x$_n$) and (y$_n$) in a metric space: 
( (x$_n$) $\rightarrow$ x and (y$_n$) $\rightarrow$ y ) $\Rightarrow$ ((x$_n$ + y$_n$) $\rightarrow$ (x+y)), 
 using the usual $\epsilon$/2 argument, it doesn't work. Somehow this seems somewhat counter intuitive to me, in that the triangle inequality, which is one of the properties you need to prove this, holds in any general metric space. It seems that the absolute value function has this additional property that we can regroup the arguments, which general metric functions don't have. In other words, I can write |x$_n$ + y$_n$ - (x+y)| = |(x$_n$-x) + (y$_n$-y)|, which doesn't seem to be true for a general metric function. 
 I know that on the one hand we can just say well it's just a basic algebraic fact and that's the way things are, but I get this uneasy feeling that perhaps there is some more general mathematical property that the absolute function possesses that allows us to prove the above result which is lacking in a general metric function.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: How do you define addition in a general metric space? Or did you mean a normed vector space?

Comment: @LutzL  I see the point! I haven't worked much with metric spaces, and the book I am using (Goldberg's "Method's of Real Analysis") deals only with sequences where addition is defined, so excuse my ignorance :>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a metric space, there may not be addition and the absolute value function to begin with.

Comment: To be honest, I guess I'm not too familiar with examples where addition is not defined (since all of the examples from the textbook, such as L^infinity, L^1, L^2, etc all have addition defined). But I think I partially see your point, which is that the notion of a metric space is perhaps more a topological notion than an algebraic notion. I suppose the discrete metric would be a good example of this, where my set M could be any set (set of all chairs in a room for example).

Comment: @MattBrenneman You can also consider the interval $X=[2,3]$ (endowed with the standard metric inherited from $\mathbb R$). Even though there is addition "in the background, there are no points $x,y\in X$ such that their sum would also be $\in X$. So once we forget the ocean of real numbers around our interval island ...

Comment: A more intuitive example might be the unit sphere, inheriting the metric from the norm of the surrounding space. Even though the surrounding space is linear, simple linear operations with points of the sphere mostly lead to points not on the sphere.